# Make div stack like hastag in css

Tags: html, css

I have the following code

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="tag">123</div>
    <div class="tag">asdasd</div>
    <div class="tag">vxcv</div>
    <div class="tag">wer</div>
    <div class="tag">sdgdfg</div>
    <div class="tag">sdfweqr</div>  
    <div class="tag">asdasd</div>
    <div class="tag">zxczxc</div>
  <div>
<div>
```

```
.container{
   font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #1c2228;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}

.tag{
  border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: #eef3f7;
    width: fit-content;
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 2px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/popoleemaster/pen/GRqXgxX

I would like to make it look like this (EDIT : this picture is 3 column, but they should be dynamic) :

[image]

with all the div stacking and taking the available space or jump line. But I can7t quite manage to find the correct css

Comment: Use display:grid a simple solutión of that can display the grid, like you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flexbox is the solution. Give `display:flex` with `flex-wrap: wrap;` to the wrapper div. You can play around with flexbox property to have the desired alignment.

```css
.container {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #red;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.wrapper {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
/*   justify-content: space-evenly; */
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.tag {
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #eef3f7;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="tag">123</div>
    <div class="tag">asdasd</div>
    <div class="tag">vxcv</div>
    <div class="tag">wer</div>
    <div class="tag">sdgdfg</div>
    <div class="tag">sdfweqr</div>
    <div class="tag">asdasd</div>
    <div class="tag">LongHashTag</div>
    <div class="tag">shortOne</div>
    <div class="tag">small</div>
    <div class="tag">one</div>
    <div class="tag">zxczxc</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a float: left to `.tag` element and try changing the width of `.container` div to see results

```
.tag{
  border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: #eef3f7;
    width: fit-content;
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 2px;
    float: left: <--------
}
```

https://codepen.io/Scorpion2009/pen/qBNMEvp

Answer (score 1):

Try using flex box:

```
.wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
  
}



 .wrapper > div {
      font-size: 20px;
      background-color: #9ddfd3;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 15px;
      
      
    }
```

(for  the wrapper div I just added some code to go along with the new sub class)

Check out this for more info:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container{
   font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 200px; /* I changed width to wrap items */
    background-color: #1c2228;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: grid;  /* this and the next line will make one row three columns grid*/
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.tag{
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #eef3f7;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="tag">123</div>
    <div class="tag">asdasd</div>
    <div class="tag">vxcv</div>
    <div class="tag">wer</div>
    <div class="tag">sdgdfg</div>
    <div class="tag">sdfweqr</div>  
    <div class="tag">asdasd</div>
    <div class="tag">zxczxc</div>
 <div>
   <div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the css grid system. the code would look like

```
.wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 3;
    grid-gap: 20px;
}
```

Comment: I would recommend using the grid system instead of flexbox, floats, tables etc because the grid is flexible and you can make it responsive without media queries

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I copy this css, and it doesn't do what I expect in the codepen. Also, this would make 3 column maximum right ?